# Do you need to unbind/remove event listeners when navigating away from a React page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am making a web app in React. I currently have page A and page B. Page A has a few event listeners bound to various elements on the page. However, when I navigate from page A to page B, I get the following error show up repeatedly in my console (like dozens of errors in the span of a few seconds):

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the LandingPageHeader component.

Do I need to unbind these listeners in my componentWillUnmount() function (of page A)? Or is something else going on? Also, does it matter that some of these event listeners are bound to the html tag?

It should also be noted that some of the event handlers for the above event listeners do perform functions that involve updating/setting the React state.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can unbind event listener in `componentWillUnmount`, or set a flag in page A component, check this flag every time before setState.

```
componentDidMount() {
    var _this = this;
    this._mounted = true;

    // in listenner function 
    window.addEventListener('resize', funciton () {
        if (_this._mounted) {
            _this.setState({});
        }
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this._mounted = false;
}
```